# Do I need to provide a decoupling capacitor network for all the power pins of a microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, power, emc, decoupling-capacitor, signal-integrity

I am using [PIC32CZ8110CA90208-I8MX-SL3](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/PIC32CZ8110CA90208?_ga=2.228789209.452720271.1706684652-2052799221.1706684652) in my design.The power supply section is given below.

You can see that it has:

- AVDD 1 pin
- VDDIO 15 pins
- VDDREG 3 pins

Do I need to provide a separate decoupling network for each pin or a single decoupling network for each rail?

What I mean is do I need to provide fifteen decoupling capacitors for VDDIO, three decoupling capacitors for VREG, etc.?

[image]

Comment: Microchip should have a dev board for that part - what do they do?  Generally it is expected that each pwr/gnd pair has a capacitor. The datasheet should also have recommendations.

Comment: One capacitor per power pin, unless there's a very good reason to do otherwise. With minimal conductor length to power pin and to nearest ground. Capacitors cost pennies. Not having enough capacitors can cost you weeks of debugging and a board respin at best, failures with the customer at worst.

Comment: A big MCU like this will surely have all manner of recommendations from the manufacturer and you need very good reasons for deviating from them. Did you for example RTFM chapter 50, schematic checklist? It contains most of the info you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do the following:

A 100nF 0402/0201 Capacitor per power pin and a 330nF 0402/0603 per "Pin-Group". A Pin-Group can be for example G7/G9/G10, H7/H9/H11.

You could as use a LC network with a ferrit bead to feed the AVDD.

The most important thing however is, that your **MCU ground pins and the capacitor GND pins are connected with a solid layer** and "many" vias and the **distance between the 100n's and the MCU pins is short.**

The "feed line" into the 100n's+330n can be either a plane or routed tracks - doesnt really matter for an MCU.

Comment: "LC network with a ferrit bead to feed the AVDD".Can you please share the design of this network

Comment: "You could as use a LC network with a ferrit bead to feed the AVDD" In that case just use something like a high precision shunt voltage ref IC. A single SOT23. Simpler, cheaper, better.

Comment: As for decoupling caps, RTFM recommends 100nF + 10nF per pin and then a 33uF per group. The 10nF is probably overkill. If anything something far smaller could go there, to decouple absorbed RF, in case of some wireless transmitter nearby.